# F# Arrays - Count Yes And No

Tags: arrays, f#

I have three arrays - **first** is a float array, **second** is a string array, and **third** is a float array comprising the sorted, unique values from the **first** array.

```
module SOQN = 

    open System

    type collective = { score:double; yes:int; no:int; correct:double }

    let first  = [| 25;   20;   23;    10;    8;     5;    4;     12;   19;    15;    15;    12;   11;    11 |]
    let second = [| "No"; "No"; "Yes"; "Yes"; "Yes"; "No"; "Yes"; "No"; "Yes"; "Yes"; "Yes"; "No"; "Yes"; "No" |]

    let third  = Array.distinct (first |> Array.sort)
    let fourth = Seq.zip first second
    let fifth  = fourth |> Seq.sortBy fst
    let yesCounts = 
        fifth 
        |> Seq.filter (fun (_, y) -> if y = "Yes" then true else false)
        |> Seq.map fst
    let noCounts = 
        fifth 
        |> Seq.filter (fun (_, y) -> if y = "No" then true else false)
        |> Seq.map fst

    (*
        Expected Result: 
        third          = [| 4; 5; 8; 10; 11; 12; 15; 19; 20; 23; 25 |]
        yesCounts      = [| 1; 1; 2; 3; 4; 4; 6; 7; 7; 8; 8 |]
        noCounts       = [| 0; 1; 1; 1; 2; 4; 4; 4; 5; 5; 6 |]
        yesProportions = [| 1/1; 1/2; ;2/3 3/4; 4/6; 4/8; 6/10; 7/11; 7/12; 8/13; 8/14 |]
    *)
```

I need a new collection generated from iterating through the **third** array and including the **yes** and **no** counts "**<=**" each of its values. Finally, I need to iterate through this new collection to create a new column comprising the **yes** proportions at each value and printing each unique value and its matching **yes** proportion.

Please advise?

Comment: Can you post any code you've already written to do this?

Comment: Taylor, as you can see, though I can identify the change points for yes and no counts I am unable to complete the calculations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, use some more meaningful names:

```
let nums  = [| 25; 20; 23; 10; 8; 5; 4; 12; 19; 15; 15; 12; 11; 11 |]
let yesNos = // convert string -> bool to simplify following code
  [| "No"; "No"; "Yes"; "Yes"; "Yes"; "No"; "Yes"; "No"; "Yes"; "Yes"; "Yes"; "No"; "Yes"; "No" |]
  |> Array.map (fun s -> s = "Yes")
let distinctNums = nums |> Array.distinct |> Array.sort
let numYesNos = Array.zip nums yesNos
```

Then if you really want separate collections for each yes/no/ratio calculation, you can build those using a fold:

```
let foldYesNos num (yesCounts, noCounts, yesRatios) =
  // filter yes/no array by <= comparison
  // then partition it into two arrays by the second bool item
  let (yays, nays) = numYesNos |> Array.filter (fun (n,_) -> n <= num) |> Array.partition snd
  let yesCount = Array.length yays
  let noCount = Array.length nays
  let yesRatio = float yesCount / float(yesCount + noCount)
  (yesCount::yesCounts, noCount::noCounts, yesRatio::yesRatios)

// fold *back* over the distinct numbers
// to make the list accumulation easier/not require a reversal
let (yays, nays, ratio) = Seq.foldBack foldYesNos (distinctNums |> Seq.sort) ([], [], [])
```

However, I assume since you posted a `Collective` record type in the sample that you might actually want to emit one of these records for each input:

```
type Collective = { score:int; yes:int; no:int; correct:float }

let scoreNum num =
  let (yays, nays) = numYesNos |> Array.filter (fun (n,_) -> n <= num) |> Array.partition snd
  let yesCount = Array.length yays
  let noCount = Array.length nays
  let yesRatio = float yesCount / float(yesCount + noCount)
  { score = num; yes = yesCount; no = noCount; correct = yesRatio }

distinctNums |> Array.map scoreNum
```

You can see this code is very similar, it just returns a `Collective` record for each input rather than building lists for the individual calculations, and so we can use a *map* instead of a *fold*.